# URL Encode String in NodeJs

Tags: php, node.js

In PHP we have:

```
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
```

What is the NodeJs version of `urlencode();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is that you need?  [urlendcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urlencode)

in this case, maybe not related to nodejs, 
in client only use javacript function [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) for encode

for example:

```js
var apiUrl: string = 'mycgi?foo=';
apiUrl += encodeURIComponent(userInput)
```